# How can the information encoded in a boundary be changed in holographic principle?

Tags: holographic-principle

When information is encoded in a boundary of a bulk, following the holographic principle, it would raise a universe in the boundary with physics determined by the information encoded on it.

My question is: Can this information (once encoded in the boundary) be modified or changed? Can it be modified without changing nothing in the bulk?